# Understanding CATransform3D rotations around all three axis

Tags: ios, macos, catransform3d

I want to rotate a view around the three axis, with 3 different angles : rx, ry, rz.

Here's what I done :

```
_tx = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rx*M_PI/360, 1, 0, 0);
_ty = CATransform3DMakeRotation(ry*M_PI/360, 0, 1, 0);
_tz = CATransform3DMakeRotation(rz*M_PI/360, 0, 0, 1);
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(_tx, CATransform3DConcat(_ty, _tz));
```

I though it was working when I tried to invert the concatenation order. For example,

```
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(_tx, CATransform3DConcat(_ty, _tz));
```

and

```
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(_tz, CATransform3DConcat(_tx, _ty));
```

Do not give the same result !!

1. Is there a way to rotate around the 3 axis with one `CATransform3DMakeRotation`?
2. Or a better way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://ronnqvi.st/the-math-behind-transforms/) helps your understanding of transforms.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll read it carefully.

Comment: Conversion from degrees to radians = degrees * M_PI / 180;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matrix operations are not commutative, changing the order in which you multiply them together will give you different resulting transform matrices.

In which order do you want to apply your 3 different rotations? That is the order that you should concatenate your transform matrices.

Comment: Thanks for lighting me. You're right, I couldn't figure out it was non-commutative since I tried two simple rotations with a real little cube. I think I have a conceptual problem because I can't decide the order my transformations must be done. The thing which embarrassing me is the fact I'm doing 3 transforms instead of only one. If there are (x, y, z) in `CATransform3DMakeRotation`, there should be a way to achieve this in one instruction, shound'nt it??

Comment: @Martin You could do `view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(totalAngle, rx, ry, rz);` where rx+ry+rz = 1 and (rx, ry, rz) is the vector you are rotating around.

Comment: Ok, I begin to understand. I have to calculate the resulting vector and angle from my 3 transformations. Maybe your link will help to do so.